# What is the difference between passing a value to a function by reference and passing it by Box?

Tags: rust

What is the difference between passing a value to a function by reference and passing it "by Box":

```
fn main() {
    let mut stack_a = 3;
    let mut heap_a = Box::new(3);

    foo(&mut stack_a);
    println!("{}", stack_a);

    let r = foo2(&mut stack_a);
    // compile error if the next line is uncommented
    // println!("{}", stack_a);

    bar(heap_a);
    // compile error if the next line is uncommented
    // println!("{}", heap_a);
}

fn foo(x: &mut i32) {
    *x = 5;
}

fn foo2(x: &mut i32) -> &mut i32 {
    *x = 5;
    x
}

fn bar(mut x: Box<i32>) {
    *x = 5;
}
```

Why is `heap_a` moved into the function, but `stack_a` is not (`stack_a` is still available in the `println!` statement after the `foo()` call)?

The error when uncommenting `println!("{}", stack_a);`:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `stack_a` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:10:20
   |
8  |     let r = foo2(&mut stack_a);
   |                       ------- mutable borrow occurs here
9  |     // compile error if the next line is uncommented
10 |     println!("{}", stack_a);
   |                    ^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
...
15 | }
   | - mutable borrow ends here
```

I think this error can be explained by referring to lifetimes. In the case of `foo`, `stack_a` (in the `main` function) is moved to function `foo`, but the compiler finds that the lifetime of the argument of the function `foo`, `x: &mut i32`, ends at end of `foo`. Hence, it lets us use the variable `stack_a` in the `main` function after `foo` returns. In the case of `foo2`, `stack_a` is also moved to the function, but we also return it.

Why doesn't the lifetime of `heap_a` end at end of `bar`?

Answer (score 56):

Pass-by-value is always either a copy (if the type involved is “trivial”) or a move (if not). `Box<i32>` is not copyable because it (or at least one of its data members) implements `Drop`. This is typically done for some kind of “clean up” code. A `Box<i32>` is an “owning pointer”. It is the sole owner of what it points to and that's why it “feels responsible” to free the `i32`'s memory in its `drop` function. Imagine what would happen if you copied a `Box<i32>`: Now, you would have two `Box<i32>` instances pointing to the same memory location. This would be bad because this would lead to a double-free error. That's why `bar(heap_a)` *moves* the `Box<i32>` instance into `bar()`. This way, there is always no more than a single owner of the heap-allocated `i32`. And this makes managing the memory pretty simple: Whoever owns it, frees it eventually.

The difference to `foo(&mut stack_a)` is that you don't pass `stack_a` by value. You just “lend” `foo()` `stack_a` in a way that `foo()` is able to mutate it. What `foo()` gets is a *borrowed* pointer. When execution comes back from `foo()`, `stack_a` is still there (and possibly modified via `foo()`). You can think of it as `stack_a` returned to its owning stack frame because `foo()` just borrowed it only for a while.

The part that appears to confuse you is that by uncommenting the last line of

```
let r = foo2(&mut stack_a);
// compile error if uncomment next line
// println!("{}", stack_a);
```

you *don't* actually test whether `stack_a` as been moved. `stack_a` is still there. The compiler simply does not allow you to access it via its name because you still have a mutably borrowed reference to it: `r`. This is one of the rules we need for memory safety: There can only be one way of accessing a memory location if we're also allowed to alter it. In this example `r` is a mutably borrowed reference to `stack_a`. So, `stack_a` is still considered mutably borrowed. The only way of accessing it is via the borrowed reference `r`.

With some additional curly braces we can limit the lifetime of that borrowed reference `r`:

```
let mut stack_a = 3;
{
   let r = foo2(&mut stack_a);
   // println!("{}", stack_a); WOULD BE AN ERROR
   println!("{}", *r); // Fine!
} // <-- borrowing ends here, r ceases to exist
// No aliasing anymore => we're allowed to use the name stack_a again
println!("{}", stack_a);
```

After the closing brace there is again only one way of accessing the memory location: the name `stack_a`. That's why the compiler lets us use it in `println!`.

Now you may wonder, how does the compiler know that `r` actually refers to `stack_a`? Does it analyze the implementation of `foo2` for that? No. There is no need. The function signature of `foo2` is sufficient in reaching this conclusion. It's

```
fn foo2(x: &mut i32) -> &mut i32
```

which is actually short for

```
fn foo2<'a>(x: &'a mut i32) -> &'a mut i32
```

according to the so-called “lifetime elision rules”. The meaning of this signature is: `foo2()` is a function that takes a borrowed pointer to some `i32` and returns a borrowed pointer to an `i32` which is the same `i32` (or at least a “part” of the original `i32`) because the the same lifetime parameter is used for the return type. As long as you hold on to that return value (`r`) the compiler considers `stack_a` mutably borrowed.

If you're interested in why we need to disallow aliasing and (potential) mutation happening at the same time w.r.t. some memory location, check out [Niko's great talk](https://air.mozilla.org/guaranteeing-memory-safety-in-rust/).

Answer (score 24):

When you pass a boxed value, you are moving the value completely. You no longer own it, the thing you passed it to does. It is so for any type that is not [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) (plain old data that can just be `memcpy`’d, which a heap allocation certainly can’t be). This is how Rust’s ownership model works: each object is owned in exactly one place.

If you wish to mutate the *contents* of the box, you should pass in a `&mut i32` rather than the whole `Box<i32>`.

Really, `Box<T>` is only useful for recursive data structures (so that they can be represented rather than being of infinite size) and for the *very* occasional performance optimisation on large types (which you shouldn’t try doing without measurements).

To get `&mut i32` out of a `Box<i32>`, take a mutable reference to the dereferenced box, i.e. `&mut *heap_a`.

Answer (score 15):

The difference between passing by reference and "by box" is that, in the *reference* case ("lend"), the caller is responsible for deallocating the object, but in the *box* case ("move"), the callee is responsible for deallocating the object.

Therefore, `Box<T>` is useful for passing objects with responsibility for deallocating, while the reference is useful for passing objects without responsibility for deallocating.

A simple example which demonstrates these ideas:

```
fn main() {
    let mut heap_a = Box::new(3);
    foo(&mut *heap_a);
    println!("{}", heap_a);

    let heap_b = Box::new(3);
    bar(heap_b);
    // can't use `heap_b`. `heap_b` has been deallocated at the end of `bar`
    // println!("{}", heap_b);
} // `heap_a` is destroyed here

fn foo(x: &mut i32) {
    *x = 5;
}

fn bar(mut x: Box<i32>) {
    *x = 5;
} // heap_b (now `x`) is deallocated here
```