# When to use a reference or a box to have a field that implements a trait in a struct?

Tags: struct, reference, rust, traits

I have the following code:

```
pub trait MyTrait {
    pub fn do_something(&self);
}
```

If I want a struct `A` to have a field `a` that implements the trait `MyTrait`, there are 2 options:

```
pub struct A<'a> {
    a: &'a MyTrait
}
```

or

```
pub struct A {
    a: Box<MyTrait>
}
```

But on [Difference between pass by reference and by box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305585/difference-between-pass-by-reference-and-by-box), someone said:

> Really, `Box<T>` is only useful for recursive data structures (so that
>   they can be represented rather than being of infinite size) and for
>   the very occasional performance optimisation on large types (which you
>   shouldn’t try doing without measurements).

Unless `A` implements `MyTrait`, I'd say `A` is not a recursive data structure, so that makes me think I should prefer using a reference instead of a box.

If I have another struct `B` that has a reference to some `A` object, like this:

```
pub struct A<'a> {
    a: &'a MyTrait
}

pub struct B<'a, 'b: 'a> {
    b: &'a A<'b>
}
```

I need to say that `'b` is larger than `'a`, and [according to the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-02-advanced-lifetimes.html):

> You won't often need this syntax, but it can come up in situations
>   like this one, where you need to refer to something you have a
>   reference to.

I feel like that's a bad choice too, because the example here is really simple and probably doesn't need this kind of advanced feature.

How to decide whether I should use a reference or a box then?

Comment: Do you have a more practical use case, so that we might understand your concern? References and `Box` have quite different semantics. Also, is there a reason why you can't go for a monomorphism? As in, `struct A<T: MyTrait> { a: T }`?

Comment: I would have to write `A<StructImplementingMyTrait>` in structs using `A`, meaning these structs would probably need this `<StructImplementingMyTrait>` too, which is more verbose than the other solutions. Is there any advantage ?

Comment: That does not sound like a reasonable drawback against monomorphisation. Typical usage is still not that verbose (`let x = A { a: StructImplementingMyTrait };`), and you can type-alias around it (`type MyA = A<StructImplementingMyTrait>`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the quote you used applied to a completely different situation.

> Really, `Box<T>` is only useful for recursive data structures (so that they can be represented rather than being of infinite size) and for the very occasional performance optimisation on large types (which you shouldn’t try doing without measurements).

Is speaking about using either of `MyEnum` or `Box<MyEnum>` for data members:

- it is not comparing to references,
- it is not talking about traits.

So... reset your brain, and let's start from scratch again.

---

The main difference between `Box` and a reference is *ownership*:

- A `Box` indicates that the surrounding struct *owns* the piece of data,
- A reference indicates that the surrounding struct *borrows* the piece of data.

Their use, therefore, is dictated by whether you want ownership or borrowing, which is a situational decision: neither is better than the other in the same way that a screwdriver and a hammer are not better than the other.

`Rc` (and `Arc`) can somewhat alleviate the need to decide, as they allow multiple owners, however they also introduce the risk of reference cycles which is its own nightmare to debug so I would caution over overusing them.

Comment: Alright, if I want to use a reference then, I still have to use that `'b: 'a` syntax, right ? The fact that the doc says I won't need it often makes me think borrowing the value wouldn't be the right choice and I can't really see why

Comment: @CarlLevasseur: It's just that it's pretty rare to start layering a reference to a struct which contains a reference to... I mean, if we start from the bogus number of 10% of structs only contain a reference, then we end up with 90% of structs have no reference, 9% have a reference, 0.9% have a reference to a struct with a reference, 0.09% have a reference to a struct with a reference to a struct with a reference, etc... as you can see, that's less than 1% of cases where you need `'b: 'a` :)

Comment: Okay, I guess I made the error of using way too much references then

Comment: @CarlLevasseur: Just because something is infrequent does not mean it's wrong! However, as you noticed, some features will put on some syntactic burden so sometimes you have to find a trade-off between performance and ease of use. If you want to squeeze out as much performance as possible, you may end up with crazy struct/function signatures with lots of generic parameters... such is life.